Gunicorn on aws ec2
Hello I'm trying to stop my gunicorn server on Debian and I can't do it I tried to kill the process but the service restarts on its own, do you have any ideas thank you
I tried several commands but it doesn't work
If anyone has an idea I'm interested
enter image description here
enter image description here
command : pkill , kill -9 ,sudo fuser -ki  8000/tcp

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you are running gunicorn on port, You can kill the process using port number too.
command to kill process via port number (assuming 6666 is port number)
fuser -k 6666/tcp


Thank you for your answer but it still does not work the process restarts each time with a new pid

one more thing you can do check all services, and find out which service using same port and disable it. check this location for services /etc/systemd/system. this command might help to find out port cat /etc/systemd/system/. | grep 
